# QString::arg() with number after placeholder

Tags: qt, qstring

I want to use .arg() on a string. This is an example:

```
qDebug() << QString("%11%2").arg(66).arg(77);
```

I would like to get the output `66177` but of course this isn't the actual output since `%11` is interpreted as placeholder #11 instead of place holder #1 followed by a literal 1.

Is there a better solution than the following?

```
qDebug() << QString("%1%2%3").arg(66).arg(1).arg(77);
```

Comment: `qDebug() << QString("%011%02").arg(66).arg(77);`

Comment: Your solution is actually more legible and compact than the suggested answers. The only change I would make is to wrap the numbers in `QString::number()`. (Apologies for necro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `arg` replaces sequence with lowest value after `%`. Range must be betwen 1 and 99.
So you dont have to use `1` index you can use two digit number instead one digit number.

Try this and see what will happen:

```
qDebug() << QString("%111%22").arg(66).arg(77);
```

This should give you expected result (I've test it on qt 5.4 and it works perfectly).

I've also tested solution form comment under the question and it works to:

```
qDebug() << QString("%011%02").arg(66).arg(77);
```

Comment: Good solution. However a bit hard to read. Definitively needs a code comment.

Answer (score 2):

The sense of `arg()` is that it is replacing everything from `%1` to `%99` that is why you should not have `%11`. There are several ways to escape this.

Your way is fine as well as you can have 1 as constant earlier in your code:

```
qDebug() << QString("%1%2%3").arg(66).arg(1).arg(77);
```

Or you can have:

```
qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(66) + "1" + QString("%1").arg(77);
```

Using `QString::number` is ok too as was specified in comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following approaches:

- `QString::number(66) + "1" + QString::number(77)`
- `QString("%1 1 %2").arg(66).arg(77).replace(" ", "")`

Comment: I will need advanced number formatting (which isn't available using QString::number). Still this surely is an alternative for standard cases.

Comment: Marek's solution is surely the universal one ***poke to brainprom***.